# How to make a rigidbody moving at a constant speed using the velocity function go up and down slopes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, I have a vehicle using a rigidbody that moves forward (relative to the front of the vehicle) at a constant rate using the rigidbody velocity function. The vehicle also may turn 90 degrees to the right and back, of course causing the direction it is moving to rotate. The vehicle drives on a floating platform, and if driven off, the velocity function is stopped so that the car may properly fall off using rigidbody physics.

I want to have slopes at various points in the game, and since the vehicle moves at a constant speed, the vehicle should be able to drive up and down a slope automatically. The issue is that I have to directly control the rigidbody's velocity to make it drive at a constant speed, so when the vehicle drives into a slope, the velocity function keeps pushing it forward without properly rotating, not letting it properly drive up the slope. How should I go about fixing this? Should I be using the rigidbody velocity function at all in this case?

For reference, here is the script I am using for vehicle movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject followCamera;

    [SerializeField] private AnimationCurve lerpCurve;

    [SerializeField] private float turnSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float speed;

    private static float turnTimer = 2f;

    private float turnTimeElapsed;
    private float clampedTimeElapsed;
    private float lerpTimer;


    Rigidbody ridgy;

    LayerMask groundLayer;

    private void Start()
    {
        groundLayer = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");

        ridgy = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        turnTimeElapsed = 0f;

        Quaternion endRot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 90f, 0f);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && turnTimeElapsed < turnTimer)
        {
            turnTimeElapsed += turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            
        }
        else if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && turnTimeElapsed > 0)
        {
            turnTimeElapsed -= turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        clampedTimeElapsed = Mathf.Clamp(turnTimeElapsed, 0f, turnTimer);

        lerpTimer = clampedTimeElapsed / turnTimer;

        lerpTimer = lerpCurve.Evaluate(lerpTimer);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Physics.CheckBox(transform.position, new Vector3(.5f, .5f, .5f), Quaternion.identity, groundLayer))
        {

            if (lerpTimer > 0f && lerpTimer < .75f)
            {
                speed = 45;
            }
            else
            {
                speed = 15;
            }

            ridgy.rotation = new Quaternion
            (
                0,
                Mathf.Sin(lerpTimer * Mathf.PI / 4f),
                0,
                Mathf.Cos(lerpTimer * Mathf.PI / 4f)
            );

            ridgy.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
        }
        else
        {
            followCamera.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().enabled = false;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I you are looking to create a custom vehicle physics, this might help:
[Very Very Valet Car Physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdPYlj5uZeI).

Comment: @Obscure021 reading about `drive at a constant speed` a doubt that this is about making the physics behave realistic ^^